# Android Studio: Passing variable through another variable doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I created a Method for my MainActivity to pass a String to my SecondActivity.

```
public void convertCurrency(View view)
{
   intent.putExtra("NO", "My String");
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

But in my SecondActivity in my OnCreate Method

```
    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_text);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    String g = intent.getStringExtra("NO");
    t.setText(g);
```

Nothing happens. But Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem myself. There occurs an error if you have two Intent objects with the same name even if they are within separate methods.

Answer (score 1):

get Your variable in this way:

```
String yourVriable = getIntent().getStringExtra("NO")
```

don't new Your intent

Comment: I tried, but I received an error message "Currency Converter Keeps stopping."

Comment: maybe you forgot to add your second activity to the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Your are creating new intent.

In onCreate method call

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra(key);
```

Comment: I tried, but I received an error message "Currency Converter Keeps stopping."

Answer (score 0):

replace `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`
by `Intent intent = getIntent();`

When you do `intent.getStringExtra("NO");` your intent Object is new, so his Extra is empty.

Comment: I tried, but I received an error message "Currency Converter Keeps stopping."

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code in both the  activities . You need to create intent and put your string into it, so your code will be.

```
public void convertCurrency(View view) { 
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
     intent.putExtra("NO","My String");                  
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Note that in the intent constructor the first argument is the current activity and the second argument will be the activity that you are starting.So in the second activity you need to recieve the string. Code for that will be,

```
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back); 
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_text); 
String g = getIntent().getStringExtra("NO")
t.setText(g);
```

Comment: I tried, but I received an error message "Currency Converter Keeps Stopping".

Comment: Can u inclide the stacktrace